# WooCommerce Custom Field not showing in email or order info

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a custom field for `customer-id` for client's ordering system, the field works and everything but for some odd reason, it won't send in an email or show in the order information in the admin areas. I have all of the proper code from WooDocs but it doesn't seem to work, my code is below. The link for the docs below.

[Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

```
/**
* Add the field to the checkout
**/
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field',30);

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'customer_number', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Customer Number <small>(Enter a customer number or leave empty)</small>'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter a number'),
        'required'          => false,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'customer_number' ));
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['customer_number'] ) ) {
                        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Customer Number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customer_number'] ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Customer Number').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Customer Number', true ) . '</p>';
}

add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys[] = 'Customer Number'; // This will look for a custom field called 'Customer Number' and add it to emails
    return $keys;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An error since Woocommerce 3: `get_post_meta( $order->id,` need to be replaced instead with `get_post_meta( $order->get_id(),` … Your number code displays correctly in email notifications and in backend too (tested in woocommerce 3.2.x and 3.3.x). So something else is doing an issue.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I went through debugging and nothing came up, that's why im super confused